# Map / Join with Bluebird and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to map and join my Mongoose Models such as:

```
MyModel.myPromisifiedMethod parameter, (err,res) ->
.then((res) ->
  # do stuff to res
)
.then((res) ->
  Promise.map res, ((eachItem) ->
    # do stuff to to eachItem
    AnotherModel.get parameter, (err,res) ->
      # do stuff with res and eachItem
  )
  join eachItem, ((eachItem) ->
    console.log eachItem
  )
)
.then((finalResult) ->
  res.status(202).send
    result:finalResult
)
```

The map is an iterator, I need it since my requests to Mongo are 50000 documents long. However above is not working, in particular the join part. I could not find any example on the net. Help is appreciated.

This is how I worked further, incorporating below answers:

```
MyModel.myPromisifiedMethod parameter, (err,res) ->
.then((res) ->
  Promise.all res.map (eachItem) ->
    # do stuff to to eachItem
    AnotherModel.get parameter, (err,res) ->
      # do stuff with res and eachItem
)
.map((res) ->
  # do stuff with res
)
.each((res) ->
  # do stuff with res
.then((finalResult) ->
  res.status(202).send
    result:finalResult
)
```

the "second" `.map` seems redundant but it works. `.each` works interestingly like a reduce, at least how I know it from Apache Spark. The `each` combines the mapped out and fullfilled promises into one array-type object.

However... the changed objects are not passed through it only passes the original object through. So I will have to implement a **global object** that is changed in each "stage".

But... this also does not work. The global object is always the last value of the `.then` before the `each` or the `map`.

In essence I still dont know how to get this to work.

Comment: What is `join` and where is it's argument `eachItem` coming from?  Also, what's going on with the first line, where you pass it an empty callback and then also treat it as a promise?

Comment: `Promise.map` does not work with iterators in bluebird 2.x, 3.x should be able to support it. I can add a JavaScript solution with bluebird if you'd like assuming you're using non-ancient Node (4.x or io.js 1.x+)

Comment: Ok will upgrade node and bluebird, no problems there. I would be happy about an example.

Answer (score 1):

one way I can think of is using Promise.all:

```
function mapReduce(inputs, mapFn, reduceFn){
    return Promise.all(inputs.map(mapFn)).then(reduceFn);
}
```

your code would become something like:

```
MyModel.myPromisifiedMethod parameter, (err,res) ->
.then((res) ->
  # do stuff to res
)
.then((res) ->
  Promise.all res.map (eachItem) ->
    # do stuff to to eachItem
    AnotherModel.get parameter, (err,res) ->
      # do stuff with res and eachItem  
)
.then((res) ->
  res.reduce (sumdValue, eachItem) ->
    # do stuff to to eachItem
    eachItem + sumValue
)      
.then((finalResult) ->
  res.status(202).send
    result:finalResult
)
```

Comment: I am now getting: `Unhandled rejection Error: TypeError: object is not a function,  Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler`

Comment: The map works fine. the "res.each eachItem" does not.

Comment: @sirbenbenji try replacing `each` with `reduce`

Comment: Now I am getting eachItem is not defined.

Comment: more or less, will post a working solution tomorrow. while mapping worked fine, i was not able to reduce.

Comment: @SirBenBenji what exactly are yo trying to achieve with reduce?

Comment: I want to create in the map db entry, in the end I want to have a count of some kind, a verification of what went into db, eg: key could be cars and i have 100 docs saved into db in the mapper, now reducebykey and show cars sum.

Comment: @SirBenBenji in `[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)` you need to pass at least two parameters to the `previousValue, currentItem to the callback, see my updated answer, also, I am not sure what kind of syntax you are doing, you probably need to pass the initialization value as second parameter.

Comment: I dont understand. I just need a simple example of a MAP/REDUCE with Mongoose and Bluebird.